# Powershell Script Remove Unwanted Quotation Marks from CSV file

Tags: powershell

I would like to remove Unwanted Quotation Marks from csv file using window PowerShell script, Please help me the on this issue.

Input

```
"aaa", "CI "-" Work", "111111", 20200210, "aaa"

"bbb", "CI -" Work", "222222"", 20200210, "aaa"

"ccc"", "CI -' Work", "222222"", 20200210, "aaa"
```

Output

```
"aaa", "CI - Work", "111111", 20200210, "aaa"

"bbb", "CI - Work", "222222", 20200210, "aaa"

"ccc", "CI - Work", "222222", 20200210, "aaa"
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `$in` contains your file data and your comma-delimited data does not contain commas, you can do the following:

```
$in -replace '"|''' -replace '^|$','"' -replace '(,\s*)','"$1"'
```

If you don't want commas surrounding all field values, you can do the following:

```
$in | Foreach-Object {
    ($_ -split ',' -replace '(?<=^\s*)"|"(?=$)',';;;' -replace '"|''' -replace ';;;','"') -join ','
}
```

Comment: your answer is working as expected however if any values are without double quotes I don't want to add double quotes. Can you please advice the same.

Comment: @user1565058, I added a code snippet to not add extra commas.

Answer (score 1):

Note that export-csv in powershell 7 has a -UseQuotes parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your data doesn't have any special characters or separators in the data, I would load the file ([`Get-Content`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-content)) and first remove *all* quotes, than pipe that to [`ConvertFrom-Csv`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/convertto-csv?view=powershell-7) to reinsert the quotes on the correct places and write it to the new file using [`Export-Csv`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/export-csv?view=powershell-7):

```
Get-Content .\input.csv -Replace '"' | ConvertFrom-Csv | Export-Csv .\output.csv
```